# Как узнать, что именно разрешено делать через sudo?

Tags: unix, sudo

Известно, что *nix-подобных ОС правила для `sudo` настраиваются в файле `/etc/sudoers`, но если в нём много разных правил для разных пользователей, особенно если используются алиасы/макросы, как удобно продиагностировать, что же именно разрешено делать через `sudo` определённому пользователю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Многие не знают, что `sudo` имеет встроенную возможность для удобной диагностики, для этого служит ключ `-l`:

```
# sudo -l -U vasya-pupkin

Runas and Command-specific defaults for vasya-pupkin:


User vasya-pupkin may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) /usr/bin/tailf, /bin/ls, /usr/sbin/tcpdump
    (asterisk) NOPASSWD: /bin/mv
```

Если вызывать `sudo -l` без дополнительных ключей, будут показаны разрешенные в `sudoers` команды для текущего пользователя. Используя дополнительный ключ `-U username` можно посмотреть разрешенные команды для любого пользователя в системе (но только если смотрящий - root).

В приведённом примере пользователь vasya-pupkin может запускать `tailf`, `ls` и `tcpdump` от рута, а также от имени пользователя asterisk перемещать файлы (удобно, если нужно предоставить не-рутовому пользователю возможность манипулировать файлами, пренадлежащими третьему пользователю).